# Custom activity shows as "started" even after completion in list workflow settings

Tags: 2013, workflow, visual-studio-2012, workflow-activity

I have created a custom workflow activity and used it in another sequential workflow project. This custom activity is the last step in the workflow process.The workflow settings in list shows two workflows- Main workflow and the custom activity workflow. **After the custom activity executes the task, it still shows as "Started" instead of "completed"**.
[image: Workflow Sequence diagram]

[image: Custom activity sample code]

[image: Workflow status for a list item]

Comment: Do you mean the custom activity completed and the main workflow status still started?

Comment: @AnasSalem Nope. Actually, custom activity is a part of my main workflow ( last step in the sequence). Custom activity is completed but the internal status shows as "Started"